# Does C# use short-circuit evaluation in conditional statements?

Tags: c#

Is the following code a good style. Can we always assume that the second predicate will not be executed if the object is null ?

```
if(someObject == null || someObject.Count == 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You could have googled [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.110).aspx) in less time than it took to write this question.

Comment: @Jon I guess searching for "|| operator in C#" was bad idea. I should have used OR. Sorry for the impatience.

Comment: FYI, both `||` and `OR` are in my experience iffy when searching. "msdn c# operators" however is not, and it lands you one click away from the target.

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=||+operator+in+C%23 did find an operator (`??` instead of `||`) - so `||` was 2 clicks away in search result...  So not that bad I think.

Comment: @Jon while I don't disagree, I'd rather have the answer on StackOverflow than on MSDN.

Comment: @rein: I 'm curious to know why.

Comment: Why don't you set the variable to `null`, run the code, and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. `||` is known as a short circuiting operator, meaning if it knows enough to return true (that its first operand is true) then it will not evaluate the second operand and immediately return true.

`&&` is similar - if its first operand returns false, it immediately returns false without checking the second.

Answer (score 5):

Correct. If the left expression evaluates to `true` the right expression will not evaluate. If you want to ensure both are evaluated, you can use the *bitwise-or* operator `|`:

```
if(someObject == null | someObject.Count == 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Be careful with this, you may not always get what you expect.

Comment: The `if`-clause above is a good example for something where you should be careful with ;) The first condition is redundant at the best. If `someObject` is null a `NullRefereceException` is raised.

Comment: @Tim Hence my disclaimer "Be careful with this...".

Comment: +1, `|` is not officially called bitwise-or in C# - [| Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) - "...For integral types, | *computes the bitwise OR* of its operands..."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. Does it have a real name? "Pipe"? How do you say "|" in C#? :)

Comment: I don't believe there is an official special name - everyone calls it bitwise-OR and everyone will understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The `||` operator in C# short circuits. If the first condition is not fulfilled, it will not execute the next one.